# How to code vb.net for website? I want the UI embedded within the web page of my browser

Tags: vb.net

I have made an exe program using vb.net but I want to make a webpage on which that exe is embedded.

Like the way [this site](http://ddbonline.ddbst.com/AntoineCalculation/AntoineCalculationCGI.exe?component=Acetone) has done.

Comment: If you have the source code, and your site supports ASP.NET, why not refactor the functionality to a DLL and call into that?

Comment: Take a look at view-source:http://ddbonline.ddbst.com/AntoineCalculation/AntoineCalculationCGI.exe?component=Acetone and you will see that they use JS to make that .exe file embeded into their website. As @Kev said, just check does your web server supports ASP.NET and there should be no problem to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you Kev.
I didn't knew about DLL. I'll search for how to refrate vb to dll.
If you know the process please tell me. Thanks again..

Comment: @VineSoft to make your .exe file to be a .dll you just have to change Application Type from Windows Application to Class Library.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa Thank you. Can you tell me after making the dll what html code should I write to run that dll on the page?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: @VineSoft I think that HTML cannot help you in this situation. As I can see they used iFrame JS to embed that to their website. You should do some more research about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the source code for your VB.NET application, the path of least resistance is to factor out the desired functionality into a library DLL. Your web server presumably runs Windows and so will probably have ASP.NET capability. Just reference the DLL in your ASP.NET project and call into that instead.

My advice is don't make a rod for your own back by creating your own CGI binaries:

1. With a CGI application you'll have to generate all of the response headers and markup by yourself, you'll also have to parse any inbound headers, cookies etc yourself. It's a lot of work to replicate functionality already present in ASP.NET
2. Enabling CGI executables on your web server increases the risk of a security compromise, either through a mistake in your VB.NET executable, or because via some other vector an attacker has been able to upload a malicious executable and run that.